# change text size or dialog size of material showTimePicker (default time picker ) of flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am using time picker in flutter

```
GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        selectTimeFrom(context);
                      },)

 Future<Null> selectTimeFrom(BuildContext context) async {
    TimeOfDay selectedTime = await showTimePicker(
      context: context,
      initialTime: _currentTime,
    );

    MaterialLocalizations localizations = MaterialLocalizations.of(context);
    String formattedTime = localizations.formatTimeOfDay(selectedTime,
        alwaysUse24HourFormat: false);

    if (formattedTime != null) {
      setState(() {
        shFromTime = formattedTime;
      });
      print(shFromTime);
    }
  }
```

[image]

and it shows following output
i need to change the size of it text size or dialog size whichever suits please help!!

Comment: Is text size settings in android is set to larger/largest?

Comment: yes it is that is why this issue occurs

Comment: yes that is the reason you can see all other text also being enlarged in OS UI

Comment: any solution for it?? bcz my client uses this

Comment: wait posting a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

text size settings in android is set to larger/largest. It changes textScaleFactor which means larger text.

You can try following for the widget you want to use.

```
MediaQuery(
data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaleFactor: 1),
child: <YOUR WIDGET>
)
```

For setting at app Level

```
MaterialApp(
  builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child){
    final MediaQueryData data = MediaQuery.of(context);
    return MediaQuery(
      data: data.copyWith(
        textScaleFactor: data.textScaleFactor * 1
      ),
      child: child,
    );
  },
```

Comment: i am using default method call selectTimeFrom , not widget

Answer (score 0):

1) if you want to just reduce the size then below property in **ThemeData**.

> materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,

2) you can change the height and width by chnaging value of this variable _kTimePickerHeightPortraitCollapsed (line no:45 in **time_picker.dart** for Portrait mode) and _kTimePickerHeightLandscapeCollapsed (line no:46 in **time_picker.dart** for Landscape mode).

if You want to change the **text style** of ok and cancel button, then add text style in **line no: 1633**.